# insert img alt text into span on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

the goal is to change the text of a span with the alt attribute of an img but so far the output has been *undefined*

html:

```
<span class='item__info'>original text</span>

<div class='gallery'>
    <img src='image source 1'
         onclick='showInfo()' alt='123412341' class='gallery__item'>
    <img src='image source 2'
         onclick='showInfo()' alt='testing' class='gallery__item'>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
function showInfo() {
    let alt = $(this).attr('alt');
    $('.item__info').text(alt); //output: undefined
}
```

while were at it:

- how can I revert the text back to the original text once you click away from the image?
- would this work with hover instead of click?

**thanks a lot in advance!**

Answer (score 2):

Pass `this` as a parameter when calling the function.

```js
function showInfo(elem) {
    let alt = $(elem).attr('alt');
    $('.item__info').text(alt); //output: undefined
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='item__info'>original text</span>

<div class='gallery'>
    <img src='image source 1'
         onclick='showInfo(this)' alt='123412341' class='gallery__item'>
    <img src='image source 2'
         onclick='showInfo(this)' alt='testing' class='gallery__item'>
</div>
```